# Find how many characters there are per line, in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textarea, character

I have a textarea, and I need to figure out how many characters there are per row, in my textarea. The characters per row changes depending on the character size, and the cols of the textarea, so I'm wondering if there is a way to find it without counting them manually.

```
<textarea cols = '5' rows = '10'>1234567</textarea> 
^----7 characters fit in a textarea with a cols of 5, and default font-size;

<textarea cols = '6' rows = '10'>12345678</textarea> 
^----8 characters fit in a textarea with a cols of 6, and default font-size;

<textarea cols = '7' rows = '10'>123456789</textarea> 
^----9 characters fit in a textarea with a cols of 7, and default font-size;
```

Comment: If not, I guess I'll just count them manually.

Comment: characters have a variable width in most used fonts, so you can get fewer "w" on a line than "i". If you want, you can use monospaced fonts, like "Courier New". Then every character occupies the same width.

Comment: @trincot There are no spaces in between characters when you're typing inside a textarea.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. If you type a space, there will be a space. I was talking about proportional font widths. If the browser's default is to use Arial in textarea, you'll have variable widths. You can check this by adding this style attribute `<textarea  style="font:16px Arial" ...`.

Comment: @trincot No, that's not what I meant. I meant the spacing in between characters when you're NOT typing a space. There aren't any in textarea, when you're using default font, at the very least.

Comment: Well I wanted to raise an issue, that is all. If you don't understand, just let it be.

Comment: I'll try explaining what @trincot is saying. In a normal font, the width of different letters are different. Let's take the letters 'I' and 'M'. You can visibly see that they have different widths. There are some fonts in which the letters all take up the same with, and these are known as monospace fonts, examples of such fonts include Ubuntu Mono, Source Code Pro, Courier New, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check below code. Hope so it will help you. Here "arrayOfLines[i].length" will return total characters in one line. I have written them on console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var textArea = document.getElementById("my-text-area");
        var arrayOfLines = textArea.value.split("\n");
        for(var i = 0;i < arrayOfLines.length;i++){
            console.log(arrayOfLines[i].length);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Textarea and button to calculate characters

```
<textarea id="my-text-area"></textarea>
<button onclick="calculate();">Calcualte</button>
```